# Codesignal.com AlarmClocks Solution

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

You are developing an alarm clock app that works as follows: the user can set a date and a time, and the app will ring every week at the given time starting at the given date until the end of the current year.

The starting date is the only record in the userInput table of the following structure:

input_date: the date and time of the first alarm (of a DATETIME type).
Given the table, your task is to compose the resulting table with a single column alarm_date. This column should contain all dates (including time) when the alarm clock will ring in ascending order.

[inout1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2ccc.jpg)
[inout2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n1kE.jpg)

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE alarmClocks()
 BEGIN
 select @a alarm_date
    from userInput, 
         (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) x,
         (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) y,
         (select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) z
    where year(ifnull(@a:=date_add(@a, interval 1 week), @a:=input_date)) 
        = year(input_date);
 END
```

I dont understand with this syntax

```
(select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4) x
```

can anyone explain to me?

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` combines two relations (e.g. result set of a `SELECT`) by appending the second operand "top-to-bottom" to the first.

In your example `SELECT 1` may look like:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
```

And `SELECT 2`:

```
+---+
| 2 |
+===+
| 2 |
+---+
```

`SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2` will result in:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
```

And so on for the other queries. Your whole `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4` will result in:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
| 2 |
+---+
| 3 |
+---+
| 4 |
+---+
```

`UNION` also eliminates duplicates. That is `SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 1` will result in:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
```

It will **not** result in:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

If you want to retain duplicates, you'd have to use `UNION ALL`, that won't eliminate the duplicates. So `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1` will result in:

```
+---+
| 1 |
+===+
| 1 |
+---+
| 1 |
+---+
```

Also note, since the duplicate elimination causes overhead `UNION ALL` is also preferred, if one knows the set won't have any duplicates anyway. That's the case with your example -- we know {1, 2, 3, 4} has no duplicates. So `SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4` is the better choice (though the overhead on such a tiny set may be neglectable).

More info: ["13.2.10.3 UNION Syntax"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html)